# Connection to Google sheets API from .net Maui application - Android

Tags: c#, android, google-sheets-api, maui, google-api-dotnet-client

Any clue on what could be the right way to connect to google API in MAUI application and update spreadsheet from mobile app.

I have created the Andriod credentials for the spreadsheet api in the google console and downloaded the json credential file which has client id.

Following is the code...

```
private static string[] SCOPES =
{
    SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets
};
    SheetsService service = new SheetsService(new
    BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer =
    GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets()
            {

                ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
                //This is my client id from json

            }, SCOPES, "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("MyAppToker")).Result,         ApplicationName = APP_NAME
    });
```

The above code shows exception as "platform not supported"
When I googled it i found the that the loop back ip are not supported by google services.

Comment: What is your target for c# build?  Core should fix any platform issues.  This looks like a Net project.  Core was developed so same code would work on Windows, Linux, and Mac without changes.  So platform issues should fixed.  Some code issues exist between IOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

The google api .net client library does not support MAUI  authorization and from what I know they have no intention of supporting it.

[Maui](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/2212)

> but we're unlikely to be able to provide support in the case that the platform doesn't behave as a netstandard2.1 platform normally should.

So the answer is drop the client library and code it yourself.  Although I have not had much luck getting any .net android authorization to connect to google mobile clients.